# Configuring Reverse Proxy on OpenLiteSpeed for Multiple Application Routing

Tags: reverse-proxy, vps, litespeed, openlitespeed

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy in OpenLiteSpeed on a Hostinger VPS. My goal is to route different paths to different applications on the same domain. Specifically, I want requests to http://nosbor.eng.br/api/ to be directed to my API, and those to http://nosbor.eng.br/front/ to be directed to the frontend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCZE9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQqIT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVRWf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHPfq.png)

Currently, I am encountering an issue: when I configure /api in the proxy context, I receive the error message Cannot GET /api/. Additionally, it appears that the configuration is ignoring any additional parameters in the URL after the slash (/).

How can I correctly configure OpenLiteSpeed to support multiple applications on subpaths like /api/ and /front/ under the same domain?

I've tried to set it up in various ways, but nothing works

Comment: It's been a while, does the issue still exist? API and front context should work. Rewritecond and rewriterule method should also work. If you still having the issue, please post on openlitespeed forum, we can discuss more from there and share the result here.